# Is there any way to put the section numbers after titles like "axiom", "theorem", etc?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

The normal LaTeX input and output would be something like

```
\subsection{Theorem (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)}
```

1.1 Theorem (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

---

Is there any way to use a `\subsection` function with two arguments like

```
\subsection**{Theorem}{Fundamental Theorem of Calculus}
```

and have it output

Theorem 1.1 | Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

or

THEOREM 1.1 | Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

or something like that?

I need some way of doing this that will still catalogue everything in the table of contents.

As far as I can tell, the `titlesec` package is not capable of doing this, but it seems like something a lot of people would want to be able to do.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `\subsection`, to build your theorem-like structures use a dedicated package. There are two popular packages: [`amsthm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) and [`ntheorem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) (and a front-end for both: [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools)). Here's a little example with a simple definition using `amsthm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}[Fundamental Theorem of calculus]
Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval $[a, b]$. Let $F$ be the function defined...
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Both packages offer you some predefined styles and the possibility to define your own.

To add an entry to the ToC, add

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Fundamental Theorem of calculus}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

EDIT: One question - how would you make the theorems number 1.1, 1.2, etc. or 1.1.1, etc.?

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton Since this answer helped you, please upvote it by clicking on the up arrow button beside this question.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I tried to do that when I first saw it, but I don't have enough reputation to do that yet. It says I need 15 reputation. (Not really sure how that works.) EDIT: I did just click the check mark, since I'm allowed to do that.

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton Oh, yes. Right. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton and what represents each digit in 1.1.1, for example? Do they correspond to chapter, section, theorem? Which document class are you using?

Comment: @hpesoj626 thanks! Gonzalo -- They refer to section, subsection, and subsubsection I believe. 

I'm not too worried about it anymore, since I'm no longer going "lower" than subsections. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton you can use `\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[subsection]`, so the structure counter will be subordinated to the counter for subsections.